# How do I “for … order by” in Saxon on Java

Tags: saxon

This is a follow on to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738705/trying-to-sort-a-node-set-from-saxon).

I make the call:

```
XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.newXQueryCompiler();
// 21 of the following
xPath.declareNamespace(prefix, uri);
xPath.compile("for $n in '/def:System/def:Securities[def:AssetType != 50]' order by $n/'def:RiskLevel' return $n");
XQueryEvaluator selector = exe.load();
selector.setContextItem(xmlDocument);
// exception thrown on this:
selector.evaluate();
```

And I get:
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

I'm guessing the '/def:System/def:Securities[def:AssetType != 50]' needs to be a node - how do I do that? And also, will making it a node then reduce it to one node rather than returning all nodes that match the query?

And this query can be complex as "node/node[@attr = '5]/node/not[node = 'dave']/node/@atr"

**Update:** With a query of "for $n in /def:System/def:Securities[def:AssetType != 50] order by $n/'def:RiskLevel, def:SecurityDesc' return $n" I get the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those single quotes in the query are spurious. You're binding $n to the string `'/def:System/def:Securities[def:AssetType != 50]'`, and the error is saying you can't use `$n/xxx` when `$n` is a string.

Comment: I took out the single quotes and still get: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

Comment: `order by $n/'xxxxx' return $n` is still clearly wrong, but as far as I can see it should only result in a meaningless sort (all items have the same sort key `xxxxx`) rather than in any error. Looking at your original post, I thought you were trying to construct a query with a sort key injected by the Java application? So I thought you would want something like `compile("for $n in x/y/z order by " + expr + " return $n")`.

Comment: Michael, what users pass in to us is something like "/def:System/def:Securities[def:AssetType != 50] order by def:RiskLevel, def:SecurityDesc" so standard XPath with an "order by key [, key]" appended to the end.

Comment: I tried "for $n in /def:System/def:Securities[def:AssetType != 50] order by def:RiskLevel, def:SecurityDesc return $n" and that succeeded, but it was not sorted. Do I need to do something other than just list the nodes to sort by?

Comment: In XQuery (as opposed to XSLT) the sort key isn't evaluated relative to the context item. You need `order by $n/x/y/z` rather than `order by x/y/z`.